# Use of View in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I was solving the problem **Filter Positions in a List**:(For a given list with  integers, return a new list removing the elements at odd positions)

I came up with

```
arr.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 %2 == 1).map(_._1)
```

But someone has suggested that below code would be faster

```
arr.view.zipWithIndex.filter{ _._2 % 2 != 0 }.map { _._1}.force.toList
```

I know, View creates unconditional collection(Lazies evaluation), But 
at which step (Method call) it will help us.
Meaning:

arr.view, creates view on which zipWithIndex will work, and zipWithIndex  will process each element to create Map of value and Index. I guess till now, no optimization.

filter method has to work on every element then it only it can skip or select it. 
I am not sure, how adding view in this case would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `view` means that all the operations can happen at once, instead of one at a time.

```
arr.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 %2 == 1).map(_._1)
```

This works, but it creates 3 new lists in the process, first it runs the `zipWithIndex` producing a new list with the result.  Then passes than new list to the `filter`, creating another list, and finally calls `map` on that list producing the final list.

So in that we creates two intermediate lists that we don't really need.

```
arr.view.zipWithIndex.filter{ _._2 % 2 != 0 }.map { _._1}.force.toList
```

This version uses `view` so if can perform all those operations in one shot, without needing to create those intermediate collections at each step.